# How to capture distinct x portions of a string separated by a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Considering this:

```
{
 author={Diaz, Navarro David and Gines, Rodriguez Noe},
 year={2006},
 month=jul # "~12",
 note={EP Patent 1,678,025}
}
```

I would like to match and capture distinct groups of names in the author field separated by "and" (in that case: Diaz, Navarro David & Gines, Rodriguez Noe) there could be more than 2 occurances

So far that [regex](https://regex101.com/r/QNAr0Q/2) using positive lookbehind captures everything in the curlies if preceded by 'author={' but I'm struggling capturing the 2 groups that meet the condition above. Help! :)

`(?<=author=\{)([^}]+)`

Comment: You can't do that with a single regex unless you are using Chrome/ECMAScript 2018 and more recent. Use a simpler approach: `var m = /author={([^{}]*)}/.exec(str); if (m) { console.log(m[1].trim().split(/\s*\band\b\s*/)); }`

Comment: I like this approach but I was hoping to achieve that with a single regex, do you have a solution even with the latest regex implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to grab the substring between `author={` and `}` and split the Group 1 value with `and` whole word:

```js
var str = '{\n author={Diaz, Navarro David and Gines, Rodriguez Noe and Another, John Doe},\n year={2006},\n month=jul # "~12",\n note={EP Patent 1,678,025}\n}';
var m = /author={([^{}]*)}/.exec(str);
if (m) {
 console.log(m[1].trim().split(/\s*\band\b\s*/));
}
```

If you *have to* do that with a single regex you should target the most recent ECMAScript standard that supports infinite-width lookbehinds.

The following code will work in the current Chrome version:

```js
var str = '{\n author={Diaz, Navarro David and Gines, Rodriguez Noe and Another, John Doe},\n year={2006},\n month=jul # "~12",\n note={EP Patent 1,678,025}\n}';
var rx = /(?<=author={[^{}]*?)(?<![^{\s])(?:(?!\band\b)[^{}])+\b(?<!\s)/g;
console.log(str.match(rx));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZGqod8/1/)

**Details**

- `(?<=author={[^{}]*?)` - a positive lookbehind that returns true if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is `author={` substring followed with any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`, as few as possible
- `(?<![^{\s])` - also, only match the next patterns if immediately to the left of the current location there is no char other than whitespace or `{` (trims the match on the left)
- `(?:(?!\band\b)[^{}])+` - any char other than `{` and `}`, 1 or more occurrences, that does not start a whole word `and`
- `(?<!\s)` - a negative lookbehind that returns true if, immediately to the left of the current location,  there is no whitespace (trims the match on the right).

Answer (score 1):

To match the whole part, you could repeat the character class instead:

If `and` is inbetween, you could use 2 capturing groups:

```
(?<=author={)([^}]*) and ([^}]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FPynC3/1)

Note that lookbehinds are not fully supported yet in all browers in Javascript.

Another option is to match the part instead of using lookarounds:

```
\bauthor={([^}]+) and ([^}]+)},
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6v4SAu/1)

Comment: Thanks that's helpfull, I refined my question as I omitted to specify that there could be more than 2 occurance and that I need to capture distinct groups, not just the whole string without the "and" cheers!

Comment: @Fabrice If there can an unknown number of names separated by  `and`, then you don't know how many capturing groups to specify. You could use the approach suggest by Wiktor Stribiżew to match the content between the curly braces and split on `and` to get the separate parts.

Comment: I've tried capturing 1 or more groups with an optional subgroup containing ' and ' but no luck ``(([^}]+)(?= and ))`` I though I could have achieved it that way but seems not :(